# Why does the after pseudo element move an extra pixel when positioned absolutely in firefox?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

http://jsfiddle.net/NgdUR/

im basically using css triangles made with borders to create a custom select box with both up and down arrows.

If you check this on opera, chrome, safari it works just fine, but in firefox there is an extra pixel on the after pseudo element (or one less pixel on the before) anyone know why this occurs?

If i change the pseudo elements to hold a background color they have no alignment issues:
http://jsfiddle.net/NgdUR/1/

any ideas?

**Edit: image in firefox,**

[image]

**How i looks in other browsers:**

[image]

Thanks

/Jai

Comment: what version of FF are you looking at? i'm using FF11 and i don't see your issue.

Comment: I cant see the extra pixels in firefox 11.

Comment: testing on firefox 8, but also not working now ive updated to 11

Answer (score 1):

I added a 1px height and width and changed the border width of each pseudo element to 2px. Does the trick in Firefox, IE9 and Chrome. IE8 and Opera 11+ looks a little chunky.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgdUR/5/)

```
.test {
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow:#aaa 0 0 4px;
    display:block;
    height:26px;
    width:28px;
   }
.test:before,
.test:after {
    content:"";
    border:2px solid transparent;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:11px;
}
.test:before {
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    top:6px;
}
.test:after {
    border-top:3px solid #000;
    top:14px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

this fixes it for me on FF11:

```
.test {
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow:#aaa 0 0 4px;
    display:block;
    height:26px;
    width:28px;
   }
.test:before {
    content:"";
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:11px;
}
.test:after {
    content:"";
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-top:3px solid #000;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:10px;
}
```

Comment: but that will screw up on other browsers, there must be a simple explanation and fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well... A few years later and still the same issue: If you tell Firefox (speaking of version 45 at the moment) something with :before or :after and some game with thick border triangles, he still miscalculates the width and height of those elements randomly by up to one pixel. Which gives ugly visual annoyances, especially in the context of flowingly responsive layouts, when arrow heads and tails become separated from their body at half of all instances.

Having to fix those in one of my projects, i stumbled over this article. But it didn't actually help out of the box. Rather gave the idea to try completely other ways.

What reliably helped in my case was:

1. Set box-sizing of the triangle to border-box
2. Give the inner content of the triangle (width/height) size 0
3. Give the outer border-box the exact wanted size of the triangle

Relatively simple, but for Firefox the only way to get him into submission to the rules. Chrome didn't have any problem with any method of sizing. Opera, despite being a clone of Chrome, surprisingly showed the same clownery as Firefox, but also the same Taming.